# Change of basis notation

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

The following is the definition of a change-of-coordinate matrix from a textbook I'm using:

Let $\beta$ and $\beta'$ be two ordered bases for a finite-dimensional vector space V, and let $Q=[I_v]_{\beta}^{\beta'}$. Then $Q$ is called a change of coordinate matrix.

There is, however, no explanation of what $[I_v]$ means, and I can't understand it.

Presumably, it should mean the identity matrix of the size appropriate for the vector space $V$. It appears that the identity matrix is the same independent of the basis (1s on the diagonal), but in that case, how could it possible take us from one basis to another?

Any help with what $[I_v]$ signifies would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The notation is $[I_v]^{\beta'}_\beta$, with the objects being what you've been told. There is no indication that $[I_v]$ has a life of its own.

Comment: The notation is to overwhelm to innocent kids, there're better conventions to handle the concept.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $I_V$ is the identity function from $V$ to $V$. This is *not* dependent on a basis. For any $v\in V$ we have $I_V(v)=v$.

Now if we have *any* function $f\colon V\to V$, then $[f]^{\beta'}_\beta$ means "The function $f$ expressed with respect to the bases $\beta$ and $\beta'$".

For example, let $V=\mathbb{R}[X]$ be the space of polynomials. Now consider two bases: $\beta=(1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots,x^n,\dots)$, so $\beta_n=x^n$ for $n\in\{0,1,\dots\}$, and $\beta'=(1,x,\frac12x^2,\frac16x^3,\dots,\frac{1}{n!}x^n,\dots)$, so $\beta'_n=\frac{1}{n!}x^n$.

We then have that $[I_V]^\beta_{\beta'}$ is *not* a matrix of all-1s. Instead, $I_V(\beta_n)=x^n=n!\beta'_n$, so this is a matrix that has the diagonal $(1,1,2,6,24,60,\dots,n!,\dots)$ and zeroes everywhere else.

(Some people write $[I_V]^{\beta'}_\beta$ instead of $[I_V]^\beta_{\beta'}$ for this diagonal matrix, I'm not sure what convention for placements of the betas is more common.)

Similarly, from $I_V(\beta'_n)=\frac{1}{n!}\beta_n$ we see that $[I_V]^{\beta'}_\beta$ is the matrix with diagonal $(1,1,\frac12,\frac16,\dots,\frac{1}{n!},\dots)$.

Answer (score 0):

$I_V$ denotes the linear map $I_V : V\to V$ defined by $I_V(x)=x$ for all $x\in V$. As you note that this is called the identity map. The subscript $_V$ is used to denote that this is the identity map from $V\to V$.

The change of basis formula requires the matrix of the identity map. Given a linear map $T : V\to V$ with $V$ being finite dimensional. Let $u_1,\dots,u_n$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be two bases of $V$. Let $M(S, (v_1,\dots,v_n), (u_1,\dots,u_n))$ denote the matrix of $S$ with respect to the bases $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and $u_1,\dots,u_n$.

Then the change of basis formula tells us that $$M(T, (v_1,\dots,v_n), (v_1, \dots,v_n))=A^{-1}M(T, (u_1,\dots,u_n), (u_1,\dots,u_n))A$$ Where $A=M(I_V, (v_1,\dots,v_n), (u_1,\dots,u_n))$.